# How do I overlay text over(dynamic watermarking) on Vimeo full screen video?

Tags: vimeo, watermark

I have this specific requirements. I have vimeo private video content that I would like to embed it on my site. I need in watermark along with company logo, user name who purchased the video. Is this possible?

User name will come from the database. So it has to be dynamically added just before user starts viewing.

How this can be achieved in Vimeo?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried so far?